# Using drive for hosting pictures linked by a web site

Tags: google-drive-api

We have many google apps script web apps, with thousands of pictures hosted in drive and linked with googledrive.com/host service. This is Google page about this [Drive Rest Api service](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/publish-site).

We have a google apps for work subscription.

Google wrote that is going to discontinue this hosting service on august 31 2016. [This is the official communication](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.it/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html%20.), but the Drive Rest Api service web page says nothing about the service being discontinue.

We  need to continue using the pictures hosted and updated on google site.

The question is:

1) This url "googledrive.com/idFolder" is going to stop working on august 31?
2) If yes, there is another way to link picture that are hosted in a web site folder on a web site?
3) I tried to use a google cloud storage. I create a bucket and a transfer, type https, putting as source the url of the google drive folder where the pictures are, but do not work. There is a way to transfer and syncronize files from Google drive to a Google cloud platform bucket?

Thank you very much for any help.

It says: "*Beginning August 31, 2015, web hosting in Google Drive for users
and developers will be deprecated. Google Apps customers can continue to
use this feature for a period of one year until August 31, 2016, when
serving content via googledrive.com/host/ will be discontinued*".

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you might have better luck posting this on the official Google Drive forum, if not already: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/drive

Comment: I did it. Thanks for the suggestion.